# getting multiple records in second query

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
select max(salary)
from employees 
group by department_id

select * from employees
where salary in (select max(salary)
                 from employees
                 group by department_id  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where e.salary = (
    select max(e1.salary)
    from employees e1
    where e1.department_id = e.department_id
)
```

This query gives you employees that have the greatest salary in their department (ties included).

For performance, consider an index on `employees(department_id, salary)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `analytical function` as follows:

**Ties included:**

```
select * from
(select e.*, dense_rank() over (partition by e.department_id order by e.salary) as rn 
from employees e)
where rn = 1
```

**Ties excluded (one random record when ties)**

```
select * from
(select e.*, row_number() over (partition by e.department_id order by e.salary) as rn 
from employees e)
where rn = 1
```